# How to set an onClickListener to a button in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a android studio project which is a hybrid of kotlin and java. I am trying to set an onClickListener to a button, however I keep running into compile time errors like the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.folioreader.android.sample/com.folioreader.ui.activity.FolioActivity}:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

This is my code:

```
 private var buttonBookmarks: Button? = null

 //these two are in onCreate
 var buttonBookmarks = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_bookmarks)

 buttonBookmarks.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Works", LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

I know that this is an easy question, however, I did not have any experience with Kotlin before starting to work on this so I find it a bit confusing. Some online solutions I have tried did not work so I am asking the question here. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You are missing a `setContentView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.folioreader.android.sample/com.folioreader.ui.activity.FolioActivity}:

Says that your activity is not loaded correctly, do you have something like this?

```
class FolioActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.folio_activity) <-- this one
    }
}
```

Once you have set the content view you will can use your setOnClickListener as before.

```
 buttonBookmarks.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Works", LENGTH_LONG).show()
 }
```

Comment: If someone is downvoting, please add a reason :)

Comment: This worked, this line of code:
    setContentView(R.layout.folio_activity)
was a bit below in the onCreate method. I just placed your code below it and it worked.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS reason for downvote : context has nothing to with his error. there is problem with `setContentView(R.layout.folio_activity)`and better use `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` without importing another package.

Comment: @Ashish I've edited the question, I removed the context stuff and now is a decent answer, feel free to remove the downvote ;)

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin you do not need `findViewById`.

```
btn_bookmarks.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Works", LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Should work fine by the help of `kotlin-synthetic` if still error then you should look the ID and make sure **they are matched**.

Note: To use `kotlin-synthetic` you should apply plugins like following

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

For more info about extension visit [here](https://medium.com/@temidjoy/findviewbyid-vs-android-kotlin-extensions-7db3c6cc1d0a)

Comment: That's a good one too, but doesn't really answer the question it's like a "tip", anyways well explained

Comment: This works also, but doesn't really solve the problem. Going to take the tip and remove the findViewByID() method.

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        private var buttonBookmarks: Button? = null

        //these two are in onCreate
        var buttonBookmarks = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_bookmarks)

        buttonBookmarks.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Works", LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

I just tried your code. It works perfectly. Your syntax seems correct, By seeing your Error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

only thing is your `buttonBookmarks` is null reason may be you are either missing the button in your activity's XML file or you are referencing the wrong element.

- Comment `private var buttonBookmarks: Button? = null` too.
  Hope It helps 
  Thanks

Comment: isn't it possible if he removes var from findviewbyid ? and just provide ContentView layout name to his activity ?

Comment: yes you can remove var and directly call setOnClickListener on findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_bookmarks)